# Show Hidden Content with jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to get a div to display after x time for new visitors, and display immediately for returning visitors. I can't figure out why this won't work and hoping someone can point out the error.

Using jQuery Cookie Plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
//Make Hidden Content Visible       
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            // set the delay with the following vars
            var hour = 0;
            var minutes = 0;
            var secs = 7;
            var thisdelay = (hour*60*60*1000) + (minutes * 60 * 1000) + (secs * 1000);

            //checks a cookie value
            //If no cookie found, add a cookie for the next visit
            if($.cookie('returningvisitor') === null) {
                var duration = 1; // days until cookie expires
                $.cookie('returningvisitor', 'true', { expires: duration});

                //then wait until delay to display 
                $(".hideshow").delay(thisdelay).fadeIn("fast");
            }
            else {
                //immediately display the content
                $(".hideshow").css("display", "block");

            }
        });
```

and...

```
<div class="hideshow" style="display:none;"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

And the JS Fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/mp2E8/1/

Thanks!

Comment: check the expire date your setting. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the documentation:

```
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

so in your:

```
$.cookie('returningvisitor') === null
```

should be:

```
$.cookie('returningvisitor') === undefined
```